# Getting a line number for nodejs errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, stack-trace, gruntjs

I am writing some code to automate a build process using the [Grunt task runner](http://gruntjs.com/) and [Node](http://nodejs.org/). When there is an error while running a task, it gets displayed without line number or file. This makes finding the actual issue a pain.

Example:

> $ grunt build Running "build" task Warning: Cannot set property
>   '_appConfig' of undefined Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

I am not entirely sure what is responsible for handling these error messages (node, grunt) as I'm quite new to JS development, esp Node. I thus like to know what needs to be changed so I get file and line info together with the errors. Stack traces as a bonus.

Comment: Did you try putting grunt.option('stack', true); at the top of your gruntfile ?

Comment: I did now. That gives me what I want. If you re-post as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I just re-posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting

`grunt.option('stack', true);`

at the top of your gruntfile.